# How to test two conditions in formula field IF

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field, if

So I'm stuck on the logic here this was my original code and it worked but I was also trying to add a condition that if `TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) > 0` is true then it would return 0. Is there a way I can make it so there are two true statements?

Original Code:

```
IF(
    AND(  
        ISNULL(LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c),
        (TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) > 0
    ), 
    TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c,
    TODAY()-LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two separate conditions to check, you can nest `IF` functions inside each other.

Given that you're checking `(TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) > 0`, you can remove it from your later `IF`. (Because you want it to return 0)

```
IF((TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c) > 0, 
    0,
    IF(ISNULL(LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c),    
        TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant2__c.LLC_BI__Next_Evaluation_Date__c, 
        TODAY() - LLC_BI__Covenant_Compliance2__c.LLC_BI__Evaluation_Date__c
    )
)
```